# Overriding window.print() in webview

Tags: java, html, webview

Since, webview does not support javascript function `window.print()`, I am trying to override it as is mentioned [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=322303).
In short, solution mentioned there is:
"Inject a JavaScript to override window.print() and call JavaScriptInterface method"

Therefore, I did following:

       1) Added following method call to the place where I create and initialize the webview:

```
tab.getWebView().loadUrl("javascript:window.print = function() {console.log('Gonna do some special "
                    + "stuff!!');"
                    + "alert(\"Printing\"); customPrint.print();}");
```

2) Created a web app interface

```
public class WebAppInterface
        {
            @JavascriptInterface
            public void print()
            {
                Toast.makeText(activityInstance, "print called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }
        }
```

3) Added above created interface to the code where webview is initialized:

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "customPrint");
```

This works fine when I have a webpage which does not have window.print() in same window ie. some html whose onClick() is like this:

```
 function myFunction() { window.print(); }
```

But fails to work when myFunction() is replaced with something like this:

```
var sUrl="www.google.com";
    var ctrlString="Hello world";
    var wind = window.open(sUrl,"PrintWindow",ctrlString);
    wind.document.write("<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" 
    content=\"width=device-width\" /><style>html, body, p {font-size: 20px; 
    width: 100%; display: block; margin: 2px; padding: 1px; }</style> . 
    </head><body><p>Hello world.</p></body></html>");
    var tempTitle = document.title;
    wind.document.title = sUrl;     
    wind.print();
    wind.document.title = tempTitle;
    wind.close();
```

This is happening because we are opening new window when print is clicked on webpage.In my case, we open a new webview when new window is opened which is initialized again. Although I think adding web interface when new webview is created should work, it is not working in my case. Need to figure out what could be wrong in this case?

Comment: Java is not Javascript.

Comment: Yeah..right!! Here I am trying to call java code from javascript using ways that android already provides.

Comment: Not sure what Jim is on about... think he jumped the gun a bit. But your question helped me in trying to override default window.print JAVASCRIPT function to run native JAVA code - ahem.. was all I needed, thanks! Sorry couldn't help more.

Comment: Not sure why but I had to put `loadUrl("javascript:window.print = function() ...` inside `onPageFinished` of `WebViewClient` for it to work. Not sure if it is related to what you are looking for though.